# Div moves down on one page

Tags: html

My page links(nav_btns), inside of my nav div, move down only on the contact page. The problem occurs upon page load, in 3 different browsers (Chrome, Firefox, IE9) and is not dependent upon page scroll or resize. I can't seem to find my solution on stack or google, which makes me think it's a silly oversight. If so, I apologize in advance, but I'm about to face-plant my keyboard.

I'm learning from this site and others, so I hope the code is legible. 
I've made the site live for now: http://ephelan.com

Tried: merging style sheets, adjusting iframe & contactbox size, begging a web instructor/student

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `doctype` and `HTML` declarations are different on your contacts page versus all of your other pages. Silly oversight perhaps, but it could happen to anyone. :)

Comment: I'm kind of embarrassed. This never crossed my mind when I was trouble-shooting. I forgot the contact form tutorial involved Boilerplate. I should have typed this page myself instead of changing just the contents. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The doctype in contact.html is

`<!DOCTYPE HTML>`

vs

`<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">`

in the others.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the total height of elements which are siblings of your div with id footer is different.  So, more specifically....

From here: http://ephelan.com/index.html

```
<div id="content">

  <!-- TOTAL HEIGHT OF 391 PIXELS -->
  <ul id="accordion-slider" style="width: 806px; height: 261px; ">
    <!-- some more stuff -->
  </ul>
  <div id="quote">
    <!-- some stuff -->
  </div>

  <div id="footer">
    <!-- contents of footer element -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Now compare this to your contact page: http://ephelan.com/contact.html

```
<div id="content">

  <!-- TOTAL HEIGHT OF 396 PIXELS -->
  <div id="contactbox">
    <!-- Some other content -->
  </div>

  <div id="footer"> 
    <!-- Footer content... -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Notice the difference in calculated (total) height.  Because the content above the footer div is 5 pixels higher, it pushes the footer 5 pixels lower than the other pages.

To fix this, all of the pages should be structured something like this...

```
<div id="content">
  <div class="crap-above-footer-or-whatever-you-want-to-call-it">
    <!-- All of your crap -->
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
    <!-- Footer contents -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Then, in the "crap-above-footer-or-whatever-you-want-to-call-it" class, make sure to set a height, and that this height is sufficiently large to hold all of its contents, regardless of which page you're viewing.

Comment: Though the first answer was the easiest fix, it's clear that I need to re-evaluate my div styles and placement. Moving the footer should also keep me from having to guess the total pixel height of what's in the content area for every page too.

Thank you for being so thorough!